# What does query_var do in register_taxonomy

Tags: query-variable, register-taxonomy

What happens if in

```
register_taxonomy( $taxonomy, $object_type, $args )
```

I set `query_var` arguement to true?

I read [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) this

> **query_var**
>
> *(boolean or string) (optional)* False to disable the query_var, set as string to use custom query_var instead of default which is $taxonomy, the taxonomy's "name".
>
> Default: $taxonomy
>
> **Note:** The `query_var` is used for direct queries through `WP_Query` like `new WP_Query(array('people'=>$person_name))` and URL queries like `/?people=$person_name`. Setting `query_var` to false will disable these methods, but you can still fetch posts with an explicit `WP_Query` taxonomy query like `WP_Query(array('taxonomy'=>'people', 'term'=>$person_name))`.

Could someone please explain?

Comment: What don't you understand exactly about the above. I think it is quite explicit in explaining what `query_var` does

Comment: I mean what happens if you do this `'query_var' => true,`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure how to explain this in more detail, or better than it is already explained in the codex, but here is a few notes

- IMHO, `'query_var' => true` adds no proper value to your taxonomy or any other functionality relating to your taxonomy
- As I read the docs, setting `query_var` to true, it makes it possible to query posts from a given term as follow

  ```
  $args = [
      '{tax}' => '{term-slug}'
  ];
  $q = new WP_Query( $args );
  ```

  First of all, this syntax is depreciated as of version 3.1 and is replaced with a proper [`tax_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) which has much more advantages over the above syntax like nesting, querying posts with different relationships and including and/or excluding certain terms etc etc. The proper syntax now is

  ```
  $args = [
      'tax_query' = [
          'relation' => 'AND' // or 'OR' . RELATIONSHIP BETWEEN TWO OR MORE SETS OF TAX ARRAYS
          [
              'taxonomy' => '{tax}',
              'field' => 'CAN BE term_id TO PASS TERM IDS, slug FOR TERM SLUGS OR name FOR TERM NAMES',
              'terms' => 'TERM VALUES ACCORDING TO field SET',
              'include_children' => true OR false, // true INCLUDES ALL CHILD TERMS OF GIVEN TERM, false EXCLUDES CHILD TERMS
              'operator' => 'IN' // or 'NOT IN'. SHOULD POSTS BE IN THE GIVEN TERM OR NOT
          ],
      ],
  ];
  $q = new WP_Query( $args );
  ```

  Secondly are all the advantages of the `tax_query` syntax as you can see from the above. With version 4.1 came a complex nesting feature which let you build even more complex tax queries
- Lastly, if setting `query_var` to true makes the relevant query variables available for use on taxonomy pages (*I'm not even sure if it does*), it is in fact still useless as the current queried object can be accessed with `get_queried_object()`

So to conclude, there is really no advantage setting `query_var` to `true`. It is purely personal choice if you want to waste time and space writing it out